# Python 3.7 - Deprecation notice regarding PEP 495 in APScheduler

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am having difficulty using APScheduler in Python 3.73. Running any script that uses this library seems to give me the following warning:

```
*/home/dave/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py:95: PytzUsageWarning: The zone attribute is specific to pytz's interface; please migrate to a new time zone provider. For more details on how to do so, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html  if obj.zone == 'local': Press Ctrl+C to exit /home/dave/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apscheduler/triggers/interval.py:66: PytzUsageWarning: The normalize method is no longer necessary, as this time zone supports the fold attribute (PEP 495). For more details on migrating to a PEP 495-compliant implementation, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html  return self.timezone.normalize(next_fire_time)*
```

Then the output proceeds as expected.
This is not acceptable.
Reading the referenced document tells me nothing except that APScheduler is not implemented correctly by current standards.  I find nothing that helps me fix this problem.

As an example, I am using this sample code:
[agronholm/apscheduler/examples/schedulers/blocking.py](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/3.x/examples/schedulers/blocking.py)

Comment: This is something the APScheduler devs need to fix. In the meantime, [you can turn off that warning if you don't want to see it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html).

Comment: **Solved!** Thank you!  I suspected that there was a way to hide it, but I didn't know where to look.

Comment: How can we hide this specific warning, keeping other warning as nomal?